# How to sync emails accounts in the Outlook apps between Mac and iPhone?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have 10 email accounts, and manually syncing is a chore.

I've Googled it, and there seemed to be no way of doing this, which seemed impossible.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by synchronization? Do you want to configure all ten accounts on your iPhone? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I have 10 accounts set up on the iPhone, and I want to access all 10 from the Mac without manually setting up 10 accounts.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm afraid that you have to add accounts manually in outlook for Mac.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem so. MS with their billions can't get this shit fixed : (